# mysql result in javascript global array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays

I need to have a MySQL table result in JS array so that i can search through the names when typed in a text box. I mean, lets say i have a table with some names, now when the page is requested, it should populate a div with the list of the names from MYSQL, the div needs to have an input box in which when initials are typed, the list below should find the names matching the keywords kind of like search.

For this, i think i need to store the mysql result in a JS array so that on the `onkeyup` and `onkeypress` event of the text box, it should search for the matching results from the array items and populate the list with only those items.

I know, i'll have to make an ajax request on `document.ready` to fetch the results from database but then have no idea, how to store it in an array and then search through that on the text box events.

Comment: In PHP (or whatever server side language you are using), get the query result and make an array out of it (structure it as you want), encode it as **JSON** and return it. Back on the client side, *parse* the response, i.e. convert the JSON into JS arrays/objects with `JSON.parse` and you are done. Have a look at the code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361231/json-php-javascript-simple-working-example) or google `php javascript ajax json example`. If you don't know how to query the database, you have to learn that as well of course.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this :

a input like this :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="userscount('getusers.php')" name="name" /> 
<div id="shownames"></div>
```

and here is js for ajax request  i use jquery for this:

```
function userscount(url)
{

        var val = $('[name="name"]').val()
        $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                data : {name: val },
                cache: false,
                url: url,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(resp){
                  $('#shownames').append(resp);
               }
               });


}
```

You can use ul li for appending

and here is php code(getusers.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
  $result = // execute your query 

   echo json_encode($result)
}

?>
```

with this you dont need a js array for search you directly search in your db

Comment: thats what i meant, wouldn't it be slower and inefficient if i query the database on every typed character? because the list of names won't really change while the user would be searching, so i thought it would be a better idea to store it in an array once and then search through that to populate the results

Comment: your records in your database never change?

Comment: @coder101: That all depends on how much data you have. If you just have 10 entries, go ahead and fetch them all. If you have thousands, make a request for every search term. Don't make the call on every keypress, make it when the user finished typing. You can then cache the results on the client side.

Comment: got it you can send a ajax request on document ready and you have your array in resp  after that you can do what ever want

Comment: @babakfaghihian thats what i asked in the question as to how to put the ajax response(the list of names) in an array and then search through that array as the user types in the text box on top

Comment: @FelixKling Could you please help me on this? I want to cache the results in some array on client side and not make the DB request on every keypress. I will have a list of some 150-200 names and currently , i make an ajax request on page load and put them in a list on the page.